# Establish a connection from Salesforce to VPN

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, security

Some of our API endpoints cannot be accessed from SFMC without connecting to the VPN network. We need to fetch information from these endpoints.
Is VPN tunneling possible from SFMC? currently, it is not possible for us to expose the endpoint because of security issues.
What are the other feasible ways to establish a connection to a VPN through SFMC that would allow access to the endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot establish a VPN connection from SFMC, but you can provide a list of IP adresses, which the security team in your IT organisation can whitelist, hence allowing for the IP addresses to access the API endpoints.

You can find all the relevant IP addresses in [this list](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion.htm&type=5)